# Autolayout and constraints not making buttons same size (despite size constraints)

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I have these buttons in an ios custom keyboard and applied the following constraints. When it runs, some buttons go into different sizes to fill the space. How can I make it so all the buttons are spaced out throughout the keyboard evenly?

Keyboard: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2krtR.png

Constraints for K: https://i.stack.imgur.com/smJNG.png

Constraints for L: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpQrt.png

I believe the problem is a letter like L is stretched so it can be 23 from the right side, but I don't know how to make all buttons stretch equally.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Your size constraints say nothing about equal _widths_ for the buttons, so the widths are under no obligation to be the same as one another. All you did was ask for the same space _between_ buttons (i.e. 2), and that is exactly what you got.

Comment: @matt If I use size constraints (Ex: Width-35, Height-30), the buttons will not be equally sized in landscape or portrait for example. I am wondering if there is a way to set the size equally and stretch them.

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't see the equal width constraints availability until I selected all the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Select more than one button (preferably all of them) and set the equal width and height constraint).